# How to calculate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<li class="wpProQuiz_answerCorrect">Cholera is not transmitted through persons but is caused by consuming contaminated water. A bacterial infection, it is common in places which don’t have proper sewage to ensure clean water. Cholera can lead to diarrhoea, toxins within body and dehydration.</li>

<li class="wpProQuiz_answerIncorrect">Worldwide, large companies are now following the example of Tuscany and medieval Britain in providing complex integrated solutions. Professor Williamson who wrote a paper on Tuscany agrees that this gives companies an advantage not provided by any other method of production.</li>
```

I am working on a small quiz project,I am calculating the score depending upon how many times Quiz_answerCorrect and Quiz_answerIncorrect class is invoked,So if the div class "Quiz_answerCorrect" is showing it means the answer is correct and the score is 1. I am calculating the "Quiz_answerIncorrect" through script also. But The issue I am facing is if "Quiz_answerIncorrect" is invoked it subtracts -1 from the total score, So I don't know how to subtract these two `<div>`s .Thank you here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h4").click(function(){
        alert( $("#question_tab_706_answer li.wpProQuiz_answerCorrect").length );
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3").click(function(){
        alert( $(".ui-tabs-panel li.wpProQuiz_answerIncorrect").length );
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the html DOM ? Only JS code is hard to understand the DOM.

Comment: Hi Smith, what you want is *correctAnswer minus incorrectAnswer*?

Comment: It means for right answer +`1 and for wrong answer -1

Comment: @Smith but where is your "total score" variable - what are you adding/subtracting score to/from?

Comment: I am calculating it from the classes, that is why i have used .length

Comment: @Smith but you can't subtract or add one to length, it's a property of each element. You need a variable such as `totalScore` which changes depending on which div you select.

Comment: It is not working only when i need to add -1 for the wrong answer, other wise it is working fine

Comment: Is there a way for you to get the total number of items?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h4").click(function(){
            var corr_ans = $("#question_tab_706_answer li.wpProQuiz_answerCorrect").length ;
    var wrg_ans = $(".ui-tabs-panel li.wpProQuiz_answerIncorrect").length;

    var mark = corr_ans - wrg_ans;
    if(mark < 0){
        mark = 0;
    }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the total number of items by getting the sum of correct and incorrect answers. Then just do **correctAnswers/totalItems**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var correct = $(".wpProQuiz_answerCorrect").length;
  var incorrect = $(".wpProQuiz_answerIncorrect").length;

  var totalItems = correct+incorrect;
  var totalScore = correct+"/"+totalItems;
  alert("Score is: "+totalScore);
});
```